# HitTest with movieClips on the stage from within a class

Tags: actionscript-3, class

I followed a simple tutorial trying to make a simple top-down game and I have this class so far but I can't figure out how to do a hit test with a movie clip on the stage.

```
package
{
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import KeyObject;

public class Player extends MovieClip
{
    public var stageRef:Stage;
    public var key:KeyObject;

    public var leftPressed:Boolean = false;
    public var rightPressed:Boolean = false;
    public var upPressed:Boolean = false;
    public var downPressed:Boolean = false;
    public var lastMove:String;

    public var speed:Number = 5;

    public function Player(stageRef:Stage, X:int, Y:int):void
    {
        this.stageRef = stageRef;
        this.x = X;
        this.y = Y;

        key = new KeyObject(stageRef);

        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop, false, 0, true);
    }

    public function loop(e:Event):void
    {
        checkKeypresses();

        if(leftPressed){
            x -= speed;
            if(this.currentFrame < 7 || this.currentFrame > 9){
                this.gotoAndPlay("left");
                lastMove="left";
                checkKeypresses();
            }
        } else if(rightPressed){
            x += speed;
            if(this.currentFrame < 12 || this.currentFrame > 14){
                this.gotoAndPlay("right");
                lastMove="right";
                checkKeypresses();
            }
        }
        if(upPressed){
            y -= speed;
            if(this.currentFrame < 17 || this.currentFrame > 19){
                this.gotoAndPlay("up");
                lastMove="up";
                checkKeypresses();
            }
        } else if(downPressed){
            y += speed;
            if(this.currentFrame < 2 || this.currentFrame > 4){
                this.gotoAndPlay("down");
                lastMove="down";
                checkKeypresses();
            }
        }
    }

    public function detectPlayer(){

    //HOW  VVVVVVVVVVV ?
        if(lvl.wall_mc.hitTestPoint(this.x,this.y,true)){ 
            if( lastMove == "right"){
                this.x -= speed;
            }
            if( lastMove == "left"){
                this.x += speed;
            }
            if( lastMove == "up"){
                this.y += speed;
            }
            if( lastMove == "down"){
                this.y -= speed;
            }
        }
    }

    public function checkKeypresses():void
    {
        if(key.isDown(37) || key.isDown(65)){ // left arrow or A
            leftPressed = true;
        } else {
            leftPressed = false;
        }

        if(key.isDown(38) || key.isDown(87)){ //up arrow or W
            upPressed = true;
        } else {
            upPressed = false;
        }

        if(key.isDown(39) || key.isDown(68)){ //right arrow or D
            rightPressed = true;
        } else {
            rightPressed = false;
        }

        if(key.isDown(40) || key.isDown(83)){ //down arrow or S
            downPressed = true;
        } else {
            downPressed = false;
        }
    }
}
}
```

in the line "if(lvl.wall_mc.hitTestPoint(this.x,this.y,true))" I got my problem. please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is `lvl` defined? If it is a `MovieClip` on the `stage`, then you need to understand that your instance of `Player` is most likely a sibling of `lvl`, this means that you need to "go up a level" in order to access it.

Although this is bad design, it should work:

`if ( MovieClip( stage.getChildByName("lvl") ).wall_mc.hitTestPoint(this.x,this.y,true) )`

What this is doing is it's finding the child named "lvl" on `stage`, casting it as a `MovieClip`, then accessing the `wall_mc` child.

If you would like to improve upon this design to make it less tightly-coupled, you should move this logic up a level into either your Document Class or some other class that has access to both `Player` and `lvl`.

---

UPDATE:

After looking at your full code, there are a few ways to fix your issue.

First, you have `Main.as` as your Document Class, however in the constructor, you're adding the `Player` instance to the stage instead of parenting it under `Main`. This causes `Player` to be a sibling of your `Main` document class rather than a child.

One way to fix this would be to add `Player` to main, then change your `detectPlayer` method to check against `Player`'s parent:

`if ( MovieClip( parent.getChildByName("lvl") ).wall_mc.hitTestPoint(this.x,this.y,true) )`

Second, it doesn't appear as though you were ever actually calling the method (`detectPlayer`) that checks for collision with the walls. To remedy this, you can place a call to `detectPlayer` at the end of your `Player.loop` method.

As mentioned before, this is not best practice. Additionally, I noticed that you're passing stage to your `Player` class and later passing it to a `KeyObject`, so re-parenting the `Player` in this way may break some of your intended gameplay.

If you are interested in refactoring for loose coupling, I would suggest modifying your `Player.detectPlayer` method to accept a `DisplayObject` as an argument and call that from and `ENTER_FRAME` listener within your `Main` class:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Main extends MovieClip
    {
        public var player:Player;

        public function Main():void
        {
            player = new Player(stage, 320, 240);
            stage.addChild(player);

            addEventListener(Event.EXIT_FRAME, loop);
        }

        private function loop($event:Event):void 
        {
            player.detectPlayer(lvl.wall_mc);
        }
    }
}
```

This would require the following change in `Player`:

```
public function detectPlayer($testObject:DisplayObject)
{
    if ( $testObject.hitTestPoint(this.x, this.y, true) )
    { 
        if( lastMove == "right"){
            this.x -= speed;
        }
        if( lastMove == "left"){
            this.x += speed;
        }
        if( lastMove == "up"){
            this.y += speed;
        }
        if( lastMove == "down"){
            this.y -= speed;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a Main class attached to my stage if you mean something like that but how do you suggest I should do something like that? I'm totally new to classes and I can't understad the relation between them yet ^_^.

Comment: I made the changes that you suggested and they make sense but I'm still getting the folowing error that I don't know how to deal with.

D:\JustDID\Game\simple\Player.as, Line 70, Column 44 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: DisplayObject.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the tutorial said I should download KeyObject class and add the stage reference to the main when I want to use it. I pretty much copied the classes from the tutorial and hardly can understand what's going on inside Main class other than simple lines of adding player to the stage. 

/ and detectPlayer function was called after each movement to check if the character gone inside a wall to move it back but since I only worked with it outside of a class I had problems adding it to the class. if you know more efficient ways for movement and collision detection I'm listening

Comment: As for your error, you need to import `flash.display.DisplayObject`

Comment: taught I should import something but did import flash.display; only ^_^ thanks you saved me after 3 days of shoveling the internet.